# Element not visible when for loop is empty

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a for-loop that clicks around a website and testing if the links are working.

But when I enter a page that doesn't have links the test obvious fails.
But i cant figure out how to stop the test instead of failing it.

This is my really simple for loop

```
public void TestT2Links()
{
    int count = LinkElements.Count;
    for (int i = 3; i < count; i++)
    {
        PropertiesCollection.driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"))[i].Click();
    }
}
```

Error Log from VS

Result Message:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=40.0.2214.93)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

Result StackTrace:

```
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
```

Any ideas on how i should stop it?

Comment: Do some error handling to see if the element is visible before you click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add visibility check before you click:

```
var e = PropertiesCollection.driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
for (int i = 3; i < e.Count; i++) {
    if (e[i].Displayed) {
        e[i].Click();
    }
}
```

Comment: I Understand the principle and it should work... but I am running into and System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException now.

Putted a break in the else statement but the loop still crashes.

Comment: @Dymond I bet this is because of a disconnect between `count` of all links on the page and the number of links tagged with `"a"`. Take a look at the edit, it should fix the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Thank you. I had some trouble first but its working like a charm now :)